# Cannot use offsets when array buffer object is disabled - lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I am making an api for my phisics engine and i am using VBO's to draw.

My problem is that i am getting a `Cannot use ofsets when array buffer object is disabled`

here is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLChecks.ensureArrayVBOenabled(GLChecks.java:93)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertexPointer(GL11.java:2657)
at com.FuZi0nHD.MyFirstGame.main.Render.draw(Render.java:38)
at com.FuZi0nHD.MyFirstGame.main.Game.<init>(Game.java:12)
at com.FuZi0nHD.MyFirstGame.client.Start.main(Start.java:14)
```

Here is my code:

Class Game

```
public class Game {

public Game() throws LWJGLException {       
    new Init().initalize();
    Render r = new Render();
    r.dod();
    r.draw();
    Display.update();
}

}
```

Class Init

```
public class Init {
private static int initListSize = 8;
protected static final Init[] initList;
public static String[] initListNames;
private int id = 0;

static {
    initList = new Init[initListSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < initList.length; i++) {
        initList[i] = null;
    }
    initListNames = new String[initListSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < initListNames.length; i++) {
        initListNames[i] = "NULLOBJECTNAME";
    }

}
public void initalize() {
    addDefault();
    Initdo();
    RunList();
}

private void RunList() {
int no = initList.length;
int i = 0;
while (i < no) {
    if (initList[i] != null) {
    System.out.println("run id: " + i);
    initList[i].RunInit();
    }
    i++;
}
}

private void RunList(String name) {
}

private void addDefault() {
    addToArray(new InitDisplay(), "Display");

}

private void addToArray( Init clazz, String name) {
    initList[id] = (Init) clazz;
    initListNames[id] = name;
    id = id + 1;
}

}
```

Class InitDisplay

```
public class InitDisplay extends Init{

@Override
public void RunInit() {
    try {
        JDisplay.setDisplay(640, 420, false);
        Display.setResizable(true);
        Display.setTitle("My Game");
        ARBBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB(Uni.ib);
        displayRender();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private void displayRender() {
    GL11.glViewport(0, 100, Display.getX(), Display.getY());

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    GL11.glEnable(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING);

}

}
```

Class JDisplay

```
public class JDisplay {

public static void setDisplay(int X, int Y, boolean fullscreen) throws LWJGLException {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(X, Y));
    Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);
    Display.create();
}
public static void setDefault() throws LWJGLException {
    Display.setDisplayMode(Display.getDesktopDisplayMode());
    Display.create();
}

public static void setFullscreen() throws LWJGLException {
    Display.setFullscreen(true);
    Display.create();
}
}
```

Class Render

ERROR IN HERE

line: `GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 3, 0);`

```
public class Render {

private FloatBuffer cBuffer = Uni.cBuffer;
private FloatBuffer vBuffer = Uni.vBuffer;
private IntBuffer ib = Uni.ib;
private int cHandle = Uni.cHandle;
private int vHandle = Uni.vHandle;


public void createNewColourBuf(int size) {
    cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(size);
}

public void createNewVertexBuf(int size) {
    vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(size);
}

public void draw() {
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Uni.vHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Uni.vBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 3, 0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Uni.cHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Uni.cBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //If a have Alfa colour change to 4
    GL11.glColorPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 3, 0);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 4 /* elements */);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

      // cleanup VBO handles
    ib.put(0, Uni.vHandle);
    ib.put(1, Uni.cHandle);
    ARBBufferObject.glDeleteBuffersARB(Uni.ib);
}


public void dod() {
    vBuffer.put(0.0f).put(0.0f).put(0.0f);
    vBuffer.put(1.0f).put(0.0f).put(0.0f);
    vBuffer.put(1.0f).put(1.0f).put(0.0f);
    vBuffer.put(0.0f).put(1.0f).put(0.0f);
    vBuffer.flip();

    cBuffer.put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(0.5f);
    cBuffer.put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(0.5f);
    cBuffer.put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(0.5f);
    cBuffer.put(0.5f).put(0.5f).put(0.5f);
    cBuffer.flip();
}
}
```

Class Uni

```
public interface Uni {
PropotiesFinal pf = new PropotiesFinal();

public FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(pf.VC_BUFFER_SIZE);
public FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(pf.VC_BUFFER_SIZE); 
public IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(pf.BUFFFERS);
public int vHandle = ib.get(0);
public int cHandle = ib.get(1);

}
```

CLass PropotiesFinal

```
public class PropotiesFinal {
/*
 * The size of the Vertex/Color Buffers
 */
public final int VC_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
public final int BUFFFERS = 2;
}
```

I was asked to give all my code so here it is.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? It's tough for me to tell what the error could be based on what you have here. From what I can see I think that the way you create the cBuffer and vBuffer might be improper. The code from how you create these buffers would be useful.

Comment: i have added alll my code @AndrewCumming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't definitively say that I know the problem but here are my recommendations:

First I would try changing:

```
GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 3, 0);
```

to

```
GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

same should go with your colour pointer, replace the 3 with a zero and that might work.

What else may help:

- Try GL15.glGenBuffers() to create your vertex handles rather than using an int buffer
- You call Uni a class though your code shows that it is an interface, I believe that it should be a class based on the way that you use it.
- From what I see here you constantly create a buffer using the same hard coded values, delete it then create it again. I think in this case you should create the buffer once and don't delete it after every render unless you are changing the values in the buffer.

That's all I got so I hope that it helps.

Comment: i have uni as an interface as it means i dont need a new instance of it to access it.